# sort ArrayList<Usable> by Date and by ID

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I need help sorting an `ArrayList<Usable>`.  `Usable` is an interface implemented in 4 classes, with the fields ID(which is an int) and Date(which is a Date variable).

How can I sort this ArrayList?  Is it possible by using an already existing method, or do I have to create complete method by myself?

For other methods I had to cast the `Usable` object to the specific one of the class to get the method which returns the value of what I want.  For example for removing a product from the ArrayList, I used this method:

```
public void removeProd() {
...
//input product ID by user
...
int i;
boolean lol = false;
for (i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
    if (arr.get(i) instanceof Vacanza) {
        Vacanza v = (Vacanza) arr.get(i);
        if (v.getvId() == ident) {
            arr.remove(i);
            lol = true; //... graphic message} }
    else if (arr.get(i) instanceof Bene) {
        Bene b = (Bene) arr.get(i);
        if (b.getbId() == ident) {
            arr.remove(i);
            lol = true; //... graphic message}}
    else if (arr.get(i) instanceof Cena) {
        Cena c = (Cena) arr.get(i);
        if (c.getcId() == ident) {
            arr.remove(i);
            lol = true; //... graphic message}} 
    else {
        Prestazione p = (Prestazione) arr.get(i);
        if (p.getpId() == ident) {
            arr.remove(i);
            lol = true; //... graphic message}}
}
if (lol == false) {
    //graphic negative result message
    this.removeProd(); }
}
```

Based on this method, how can I sort the array by ID and by Date?  Each class has methods for returning id and date by getID() and getDate().

Comment: Unrelated, but yikes... I'd strongly consider wrapping up that class-specific stuff in an interface, and eliminate a ton of scary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Usable` interface looks like this:

```
public interface Usable {
    Date getDate();
    Integer getId();
}
```

You can sort on a `Comparator` like so:

```
Collections.sort(usables, new Comparator<Usable>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Usable o1, Usable o2) {
        int dateComparison = o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());  //compare the dates
        if (dateComparison == 0) {  //if the dates are the same,
            return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());  //sort on the id instead
        }
        return dateComparison;  //otherwise return the result of the date comparison
    }
});
```

### Edit to address the code in the question

It seems like you are not leveraging your `Usable` interface properly.

If `Vacanza`, `Bene`, `Cena`, and `Prestazione` implement `Usable`, they should look like this:

```
public class Vacanza implements Usable {

    private Date date;
    private Integer id;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

If all your concrete implementations look like that (and your code shouldn't compile if they don't...), then `removeProd()` looks more like:

```
int i;
boolean lol = false;
for (i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
    Usable usable = arr.get(i);
    if (usable.getId() == ident) {
        arr.remove(i);
        lol = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: my god mate, i come from c programming and after seeing your solution i just realized that i still have in mind too much procedural programming i just lost so much time writing that code instead of using a proper interface, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an interface like this one:

```java
interface MyInterface {
    public int getID();
    public Date getDate();
}
```

And implement an `ArrayList<MyInterface>` instead of `ArrayList<Object>`:

```java
List<MyInterface> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

Your classes `Vacanza`, `Bene`, `Cena` and `Prestazione` must implement the interface `MyInterface`, and you will be able to put them in the array. Moreover, you will avoid these terrible casts.

Then you will be able to call `Collections.sort()`, and implement the `Comparator<MyInterface>` to sort your datas.